# Can I declare an application-wide constant?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that should exist only once but other classes need this instance. Should I explicitly pass it to each constructor (method 1) or can I just instantiate once and export this variable (method 2)?

```js
// foo.ts (the shared class)
class Foo {
  // ...
}
```

Method 1:

```js
// bar.ts (one of the classes using Foo)
class Bar {
  constructor(foo: Foo) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```js
// a file containing the instantiation (how to name it?)
import {Foo} from './foo';

export const foo = new Foo();
```

```js
// bar.ts
import {foo} from './theFileContainingTheInstantiation';
class Bar {
  // use foo
}
```

I know that a global variable is not recommended but in my opinion the method 2 is much better as I don't have to add an argument to each class constructor and the unique instantiation is guaranteed (I don't have to ensure that a unique instance is passed to each classes).

Comment: If you have only a single instance, there's absolutely no reason to use a `class` at all. Simply export an object literal from `foo.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Use read only property

```
export class Foo {
    readonly myReadOnlyProperty = 1;
}
```

And export it. To read it just do

```
import {Foo} from './foo';
var cfoo = new Foo();
console.log(cfoo.myReadOnlyProperty) // 1
```

You can also import classes. First export `foo` and add some methods for testing

```
export class Foo {
    readonly myReadOnlyProperty = "Say";
    hello() {
        return "Hello,";
    }
}
```

Then in your file which needs `foo`. You need to extend the class

```
import {Foo} from './foo'; // we get foo from other file
class Bar extends Foo { // we extend foo with our new class to get it's methods
  world(){
    let val = this.hello(); // here you can access foo's methods
    console.log(this.myReadOnlyProperty + " " + val + " world"); // Say Hello, world
  }
}
let funct = new Bar();
funct.world(); // run it
```